# Extract images links from javascript img tag in HTML files in java

Tags: javascript, java, html, tags

I'm using apache tika parser for parsing html files and tika extracts images links inside img tags such as below:

```
<img ....some variables... src="http://some image.jpg" ....some variables...>
```

but it could not extract images links such as:

```
<img ....some variables... image-src="http://some image.jpg" ....some variables...>
```

or:

```
<img ....some variables... data-original="http://some image.jpg" ....some variables...>
```

or some other variables insted of "src".
Is it possible to extract such these images links in java?

Comment: yes, just like src attribute you can define it also to look for image-src attribute no difference

Comment: @Saar, The problem is that different sites define different attributes for displaying images. I want to implement a general mechanism to extract any image link with any attribute from HTML file.